# Recover deleted MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, homebrew

Soo I did a kind of big whoopsie and uninstalled homebrew without thinking about the consequences.

However I did install MySQL using homebrew some months ago, and now I realized that it will deleted MySQL as well.

Now I lost all the database I used to work with using MySQL on my laptop.

Is there any way I can recover the data from there or is it gone for good?

Comment: Cannot be sure about MAC but on windows if you uninstall MySQL it does not remove the databases. So it is possible to reinstall MySQL and then reassign the databases if you use the same version of MySQL. I woudl suggest you a) look for the database files first and then b) backup those files before trying this, so you can have more than one attempt if you mess something up

Comment: I'm also pretty sure it just uninstalled the binary of mysql and not the data of the database. I'm not exactly sure where the homebrew MySQL installation stores the database but I think it should be `/usr/local/var/mysql`, check if it is there, make a backup of the folder, reinstall mysql using homebrew, and if you are lucky it ist back again. But you have to be really sure that you did a backup of everything.

Comment: Besides that macOS comes with TimeMachine, do you have TimeMachine active, and did you do regular backups? TimeMachine should however be the last resort, as it might have a hot copy of the MySQL data which might not be usable at all, incomplete or partially corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far @RiggsFolly @t.niese :) I already reinstalled mysql, I but all databases I had are gone. I also looked into time machine back up, but didn't find any `.sql` files there.

Comment: `I already reinstalled mysql, I but all databases I had are gone`: Why did you do a reinstall before you found the files? The database does not consist out of  `.sql` files. The data directory of the database contains several directories named the same way as your databases.  And in those directories contain multiple files that are named after your tables with suffixes like `.frm`, `.MYD`, `.MYI`

Comment: @t.niese because I just ran a script that installs numerous Programms after installing home-brew. I just didn't think about it before running it.

Comment: Are you able to locate those files I have mentioned in your Time Machine backup.

Comment: @t.niese no i am not able to locate them :/

Comment: Are you able to locate the directory for your current mysql installation that is empty?